# L6491 half bridge gatedriver is destroyed regularly

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, design, inverter, gate-driving, step-down

I'm trying to build a power supply - combined  step-down converter and the inverter using only a single H bridge and power LC member (C91, C92 = 2 pieces of 1.5uF foil capacitor in paralel and coil 1,2mH connected between ST1, ST2). I have problem with L6491 - bootstrap half bridge gatedriver. When I turn on L64941 for the first time, everything works. After the second or third turn on, the L6491 circuit is regularly destroyed and act as short circuit on 12V rail.  I designed this power supply for 300V input voltage, 20kHz switching frequency, 8,4 A output current with 1,2A ripple. This power supply feds 24 Ohm power resistor. L6491 is driven with PWM signal to create AC output 50hz trapezium signal (almost rectangle with 1ms rising edge). At first I tried to power my supply from 120V supply - it didn t work succefully and L6491 was destroyed. I also tried to bring 120V supply first and after I turned PWM signal a nd L6491 was destroyed. I also tried reverse order (pwm first and after a bring 120V supply) and L6491 was destroyed. All STP24N65M2 power mosfet (16A Id) in H bridge with 3.2 ohm gate rezistor survived. These 3.2ohm gate rezitors limits current to 3.5A with 11V rail. (L6491 is 4A gatedriver).

I suspect that the cause of the problem could be internal comparator (pin CP +, CP-) in 15A (maximum) overcurrent protection. Pin ~SD are connected with external pull up to 5V rail. When overcuurent is acticve, it should set logical 0 on ~SD pin. SD pin is alwazs high, i can see only very short spikes to 0V (interference ? )

Especially when output AC voltage is changing polarity, I measured with oscilloscope short spikes of high-voltage (I do not know whether it is not only measured interference ) and the negative overshoot on 20 miliOhm current measurement sunts R58, R132. These spikes (filtered with RC elements R15, C25 and R16 C28) would probably have caused activation of 15A overcurrent protection and disconnects gatedriver from MOSFETs.

Has someone had a similar problem with high-side bootstrap gatedrivers? Can someone tell me whether these impulses could be the cause of repeated destruction L6491? Or does anyone have any idea what else could be causing destruction of L6491 or how to proceed? When I will receive a new gatedriver L6491 (i hope this week), I will try to disconnect the comparator.

Detail: +DC_menic is input pin for max 300V DV voltage of my power supply. 
ac1_MENIC AND ac2_MENIc is output for AC voltage from my power supply.
Pins ST3 and ST4 are interconnected and intended for future improvemnets.

Thanks for answer.

[image]

Comment: What is purpose of R2 and R3.

Comment: R2 and R3 in paralel AND also fast diodes D4, D3 should eliminate negative voltage transient problem. It is based on application note AN-6706, page 12. But I never tried it before.  [link]https://www.fairchildsemi.com/application-notes/AN/AN-6076.pdf[\link]

Answer (score 1):

Source of my problem is dv/dt and parasitic capacitance Cgd (gate drain capacitance, sometimes named Crss in datasheets). Nice description of this problem is here [Cgd dv/dt problem in synchronnous buck](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/syncbuckturnon.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535748797b3fd6)

Solution - slow down high side mosfets, 0 Ohm shutdown gate resistors (only fast diode in series),  use RC snubber.